# C# Draw Bitmap CMYK value

Tags: c#, bitmap, histogram, bitmapimage, cmyk

I'm creating a program which draws the histograms of a certain photo (bitmap).

I start from a Bitmap image, which gets and draws the histogram of that bitmap. Next I do a contrast stretch (which shows the result of the photo and the new histogram). My program also provides the picture with only R, G or B values (also draws the histogram of those).

Now I am at the part where I am stuck. I want to convert the RGB values to the CMYK values. I have a method for that, but I can't draw the resulting picture out of these CMYK values (for example: picture only with cyan value, pictures only with magenta value, etc.).

For as far as I know, it doesn't seem to draw the bitmap with the CMYK color model.

Now my question is, is there a possible way to draw the bitmap picture with only the cyan values? And is it possible without any libraries? If not, which librar(y)ies should I use?

**Update:**

[Histogram of Yellow channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDz4t.png)

Could this be the right histogram for the Yellow channel? Or do I still need to do some other calculation for it?

Comment: It's difficult to tell if the histogram is correct or not from the image you posted... can you provide more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to plot only the cyan values, and assuming you want shades ranging from white to 100% cyan, then you can use RGB values as follows:
For 100% cyan use RGB 0,255,255
For 100% white (i.e. zero cyan) use RGB 255,255,255
For intermediate values use RGB 255-cyanValue,255,255 (where cyanValue = the value for cyan assuming a range of 0 to 255).

This works for magenta and yellow also, but based on RGB 255,0,255 and 255,255,0 respectively.

For K, just vary all RGB values from 0,0,0 to 255,255,255.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks! this helped me out to get the pictures in the individual C, M, Y values! However , I'm not sure if the corresponding histograms are right. I've updated my post!